# Why does this code raise RecursionError on line 11?

Tags: python, recursion

Why does this code raise RecursionError on line 11?

```
def my_class_decorator(cls):
    class DoNothing(cls):
        pass

    return DoNothing


@my_class_decorator
class Echo:
    def __init__(self):
        super(Echo, self).__init__()
        print("hello world")


Echo()
```

I got the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: when you call ```Echo``` you are calling your decorator which create a class ```DoNothing```that inherit from the ```Echo``` which means that you will call the decorator again , this leads to infinite recursion calling. just try to print before calling the super init and you will see.

Comment: @AbdeslemSMAHI: No, that is not at all how decorators work. The class decorator is called only once, upon class definition. Inheriting from the original `Echo` does not cause reexecution of the decorator.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I know, but each time he is defining the ```DoNothing```class which inherit from ```Echo```he recall the decorator , that what I meant

Comment: @AbdeslemSMAHI: No, that doesn't happen. One easy way to show this is to remove the `Echo()` call. If your explanation were correct, the stack overflow would occur anyway, because it would be triggered by class definition, not instantiation. However, [no error occurs](https://ideone.com/NhSTWC).

Comment: Also, you can avoid the stack overflow by [changing the `super` call to use 0-argument `super`](https://ideone.com/WVq2wQ). If your explanation were correct, this would have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your code executes

```
super(Echo, self).__init__()
```

`Echo` is the subclass created by your decorator, not the original `Echo` class. That means that the `super(Echo, self).__init__` lookup finds the `__init__` method you wrote, not `object.__init__`. Your `__init__` method ends up calling itself over and over instead of calling `object.__init__`.

It's a good idea to avoid creating subclasses in decorators, to avoid this kind of problem. If you want to make a subclass anyway, you can use 0-argument `super()` to make sure `super` sees the original `Echo` instead of the decorator-created subclass:

```
@my_class_decorator
class Echo:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("hello world")
```

Answer (score 1):

The super() function is used to give access to methods and properties of a parent or sibling class. The super() function returns an object that represents the parent class.
And so if we go step by step with your code.

```
def my_class_decorator(cls):
class DoNothing(cls):
    pass

return DoNothing


#@my_class_decorator
class Echo:
    def __init__(self):
       super(Echo, self).__init__()
       print("hello world")

Echo = my_class_decorator(Echo) # It's going to decorate your class
# Echo will be in this case the class DoNothing which is inherited from Echo 
# class 
Echo() # calling Echo means you are going to call DoNoting class and  
# which will invoke parent __init__ function. In __init__ method, we have 
# super(Echo, self).__init__() 
# which mean we will call DoNothing parent __init__ method again because the 
# class Echo decorated. Something like this will happen 
# super(DoNothing, self).__init__()
# become DoNothin cls
```